# How to extract a text or table from XPS file to matlab

Tags: matlab, extract, xps, xpsdocument

I have some XPS files which contains text, tables and charts.
I need to extract the data in the tables to my matlab code and proceed them.
Would you please help me in writing this extraction code in Matlab.
Thanks

Comment: please make a little search effort. This information is easily accessible in the documentation. Search for `xlsread` for instance.

Comment: But my file is a .xps no xls and a excel file.

Comment: ooops ! Sorry, my bad !

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no existing tool to directly import data strored in an XPS file in Matlab.

However, as an XPS document is nothing more than a XML document, I would suggest to use [`xmlread`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlread.html?refresh=true) to open the document and convert it to a Matlab structure, such that you don't have to parse the XML content yourself.

Then you will have to navigate in this XML structure to get the information you want.

Comment: Error using xmlread (line 98)
Java exception occurred:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.

 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)

 at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)

 at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)

Comment: OK. Can you edit your question and add a link to the XPS file ? Also, can you tell us what information you need to extract from the XPS file exactly ?

Comment: Yes I added this XPS tag before. My xps files have some information contains and charts that I need to extrat the table data to my matlab code.

Comment: This is why you don't answer help-vampire questions.